# Call to js function from code-behind not working?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a function I'd like to use to call a js function in my aspx page. I'm using the ClientScript route. However, I've looked up several forums and it just doesn't seem to be working. I hope it's something simple..I've tried it with and without the "page."

my behind code:

```
   protected void btOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["demog"] = 144;
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "closeWindow", "closeWin();", true);
    }
```

the js function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function closeWin() {
            alert("closing!");
              GetRadWindow().close();
          }
        function GetRadWindow() {
            var oWindow = null;
            if (window.radWindow)
                oWindow = window.radWindow;
            else if (window.frameElement.radWindow)
                oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
            return oWindow;
        }
      </script>


            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnOpen" runat="server" Text="Open" OnClick="btOpen_Click">
                               <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbOpen" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
                          </telerik:RadButton>
               </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

I have a cancel button that calls closeWin() as its onClientClick and works fine. Could it because I'm using onClick, not onClientClick or something?

Comment: Your OnClick will call the btOpen_Click server side code. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: yes, and then I wanted to call the js function at the end of btOpen_Click

Comment: @WillTuttle - look into jQuery and ways of calling to the server-side to do things instead of trying to get the ASP.NET page lifecycle to play well with your JavaScript. I would suggest using an ASP.NET Page Method to save your data to the server-side Session cache and then the success callback of a jQuery AJAX call could just call your `closeWin()` function. You will save yourself a lot of headaches trying to get client-side functionality the more you move away from the ASP.NET post back cycle.

Comment: Take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215722/call-javascript-function-from-codebehind-on-button-click It's a similar question to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Try using ScriptManager

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof (Page), UniqueID, 
  "closeWin();", true);
```